# How to do the lighting Of this character as shown in the image

Tags: rendering, texturing, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I have been trying to figure out for the pass two days how to use the lighting to achieve the character as shown in the image below, [image]

I tried changing textures, roughness etc but still failed everytime, please help and i want to render in eevee not cycles.

This is my work [image]

Comment: so it looks like you're close to what you show, no? Maybe use a bit of Subsurface, or a bit of Emission? Also lower down the Specular value in the Principled BSDF?

Comment: Actually, there is just a minute difference, my character is a bit on the brighter side and the colors look pale even after using the same model, and my edges are too sharp as compared to the image